# Issue with Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

I have the follow class which I'm trying to wire up to the radio buttons

```
public class ProductFilter
{
    public bool Tubs { get; set; }

    public bool Packs { get; set; }
}
```

And I use this on the view as so

```
 <div class="row col-lg-12" id="filters">
        <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Filter.Tubs, true) Tubs
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Filter.Packs, true) Packs
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now when the page loads, and I select say tubs it posts back to the controller and I'm able to filter, when the page reloads and I select packs it posts back but the values for the both are the same, I would expect tubs to be false because I have selected packs and vice versa, can some one point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Radio buttons are designed to be used in groups (allowing selection of one from a group). You have given each radio button a different name so each button is a different group and allows independent selection. Not sure exactly what you expect, especially as you just have 2 boolean properties (so you should be using a checkbox to bind them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to filter based on either a value of "Tubs" or "Packs", in which case you model is wrong. You need a property that posts back either of those strings, for example

```
public string Filter { get; set; }
public List<string> FilterList { get; set; }
```

and in the controller

```
model.FilterList = new List<string>() { "Tubs", "Packs" };
model.Filter = "Tubs"; // set default
```

and in the view

```
@foreach(var option in Model.FilterList)
{
  <label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter, option, new { id = option })
    <span>@option</span>
  </label>
}
```

which will generate 2 radio button with `name="Filter"` and values of `value="Tubs"` and `value="Packs"`, and allow selection of only one.

Alternatively you could use an enum for the filter values.